# md-max date working but getting this angular error as soon as I am setting md-max-date

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I am trying to set a max date of today like this:

```js
My controller:

vm.maxDate= maxDate;
function maxDate() {
    return new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), (new Date()).getMonth(), (new Date()).getDate());
}
```

My HTML:

```
<md-datepicker
             md-placeholder="Date of Creation"
             md-max-date="myCtrl.maxDate()"
             ng-model="myCtrl.form.startDate">
</md-datepicker>
```

It is working as expected and user is not able to select anything after maxDate. But as soon as I write md-max-date="myCtrl.maxDate()" in my html, I get this angular error. I don't know why this is happening. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

This is the link to the error
[Link To Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D%5D)

This is the error:

> Error: $rootScope:infdig
>   Infinite $digest Loop
>
> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z"}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z"}]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the controller to initialize the max date:

```
vm.maxDate= initMaxDate();
function initMaxDate() {
    return new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), (new Date()).getMonth(), (new Date()).getDate());
}
```

HTML

```
<md-datepicker
     md-placeholder="Date of Creation"
     md-max-date="myCtrl.maxDate ̶(̶)̶ "
     ng-model="myCtrl.form.startDate">
</md-datepicker>
```

When an AngularJS template contains an AngularJS expression with a function, the framework execute the function multiple times until the expression stabilizes. Since the function returns a new Date object each time, the scope variable never stabilizes, resulting in an [$rootScope:infdig error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22,%22oldVal%22:%222017-06-18T04:00:00.000Z%22%7D%5D%5D)

AngularJS separates an app into Model, View, and Controller. The controller creates and modifies the model, the template renders the view according to the model. The template should never *create* the model. It should only render the view according to the model and furnish events to the controller for *modification* of the model.

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg for the solution and the explanation to this error.

Comment: nice explanation!!

Comment: While the template can do many things with Angular Expressions, that power should be used wisely.

Answer (score 0):

I think MIN and Max will take variable instead of function as inputs

```
<md-datepicker
             md-placeholder="Date of Creation"
             md-max-date="myCtrl.maxDate"
             ng-model="myCtrl.form.startDate">
</md-datepicker>
```

Controller

```
var today = new Date();
$scope.maxDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.setMonth(), today.getDate());
```

Note:- Why are you creating  new data for year, month and date you can try like this. it easy and correct way to do.
More info
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

plnkr.co/edit/jEd8I2IbxypVPu0uGU1y?p=preview

Comment: I was trying to do it this way as shown here material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker but it was not working. It removes the error but max date does not work

Comment: your are doing differently. your assigning function instead of variable.

Comment: I tried initially with function as shown here.https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker . Then I moved to function.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jonnysai but georgeawg's solution works. I think that's the issue. His explanation made sense with the error thrown by angular: that the scope variable never stabilizes, resulting in an $rootScope:infdig error

Comment: ohh great !!. but i already plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/jEd8I2IbxypVPu0uGU1y?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jonnysai